# What's the cause of those AC pressures

Tags: ford

2011 Ford Escape XLT 3.0. 140,000 mi.
Compressor activated on request. Constantly engaged until commanded off. Low side reads over 120 and 215 on high side. These are the readings with compressor engaged, with compressor deactivated and static. Occasionally the compressor will rumble. Any ideas why these readings are so squirrelly?

Comment: I'm wondering if your expansion valve is bad.

Comment: I have little to no experience in A.C. Just some schooling. Researching what I think it might be is expansion valve or compressor. But lack of experience leaves me stumped.